# Do I get credit for creating a tag if the edit was rejected, but then the OP made the same edit?

Tags: support, tags, suggested-edits

I created the [winterbash](/questions/tagged/winterbash) tag [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23261) and the OP rejected my edit and then made the same edit to get a hat ([source](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1709054#1709054))

Do I still get credit for creating the tag?

There is no indication anywhere of **who** created it, so I will never know unless I get [a badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist) or someone tells me.

Comment: Something else I was thinking of is that the winterbash tag existed in the past, so I don't think you or I would get the credit.  They had deleted it in favor of year specific ones when the 2013 event came about.

Comment: So you can get a hat for creating a tag... Hmmm....

Comment: @Won't Hats? What hats?

Comment: Whilst it reads well I suspect there'll be those who disagree with the tag as was @Won't.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see a tag hat on the winterbash page.  You sure of that?

Comment: Also, [meta-tag:hat-whoring] is funnier.

Comment: @Won't - And despite the roll back the tag still exists.

Comment: @MartinSmith as does [meta-tag:qwertynl-is-cool]

Comment: @MartinSmith: Tags get cleaned up by a scheduled process, so it will hang for awhile.

Answer (score 1):

If your suggested edit is rejected you won't get credit for any tag creations that may have happened were it to be approved, no.

That someone went and manually made an edit later that makes the same change is irrelevant.

Comment: Any backup on that statement.

Comment: @LanceRoberts Common sense?  The obvious abuse that would ensue if it weren't the case?

Comment: @Servy Common sense is **never** common...

Comment: @qwertynl Uncommon sense then.

Comment: How could you abuse creating tags that aren't approved?  In hopes that someone will create the tag someday, and you'll get the credit?

Comment: I am creating the [meta-tag:qwertynl-is-cool] tag for future use @LanceRoberts :-D

Comment: @LanceRoberts If you were to get a hat for trying, and failing, to create a tag, it would be rather meaningless.  It would encourage people to go around suggesting edits they'd know would be rejected, just to get a hat.

Comment: I didn't know there was a hat for creating tags.

Comment: @LanceRoberts If only there weren't.  I'm quite confident it's cause way more mis-taggings than improved taggings.

Comment: Interesting, I created a tag on Meta recently, but guess I don't know which secret hat is for tag creation.  I have a few I'm not sure how I got.

Comment: Without backup this answer is worthless. It is certainly conceivable to me that the new tag would end up inserted into the tag table with the createdby being the editing user and that the code to roll back edits wouldn't bother checking if a new tag was created (as if never used it automatically gets cleaned up by a scheduled task anyway).

Comment: @MartinSmith That's assuming suggested edits are made and then rolled back if cancelled.  They're not.  The edit was never made, and thus it never happened.  If it were to happen it would be an obvious bug.  To get credit for an edit that was never applied in the first place makes no sense.  If the edit was successfully applied and then rolled back would be an interesting case that I really wouldn't theorize about.

Comment: Well I suppose it depends if they actually store a "created by" at all for tags. Maybe it is just deduced by looking at the earliest successful edit in which that tag is applied in which case it would be as you suggest. Both would be reasonable schemes IMO.

Comment: There's a "created by" field for all tags, @Martin. However, to create a tag you have to actually edit it into a post - and a rejected suggested edit does not do this. In addition, you can be the "creator" of a tag that existed in the past and is still recorded in the revision history of numerous posts, simply by re-adding it to a question after the tag has been deleted - in theory (and probably in practice) a tag could then have multiple creators over the years. In a sense, there's the tag, and then the *idea* of the tag...

Comment: *ahem* - don't post a comment just to thank me, @Martin - up-vote it if it's useful.